# In php foreach loop bootstrap Carousel display 6 product each time

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

how to display 6 product each time in bootstrap carousel in php foreach loop
i want to display 6 product in one slide and next slide have another 6 product and so on.......
how it is possible

i have try this code but not meet my require display all product at time .

```
      <?php
      $data= $this->main->viewbook();
      $r=0;
         foreach ($data as $row){
              if($r==0){ ?>   
        <div class="item active"> 
        <?php   } if($r%6==0) {  ?>  
                <div class="item"> 
              <?php } ?>
                      <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumbnails">
                 <div class="fff"> 
                 <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
                         <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
                            <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> <?php  echo $row->BookID; ;?></strong><br>
                  Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
                 <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
                 </div>
                      </div>
                   <?php $r++; if($r%6==0) {  ?>  
              </div> 

                   <?php } } ?>
            </div>


    <a class="left carousel-control"  href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

           <!-- /.control-box -->   

        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit loop for display carausel in slide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498204/limit-loop-for-display-carausel-in-slide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected your code, check it below and i hope it will work for you.

```
    <div class="item active">
<?php
    $data= $this->main->viewbook();
    $r=1;
    foreach ($data as $row){

        if($r%6==0) {
            echo '</div><div class="item">';
        }
?> 
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 thumbnails">
    <div class="fff">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/css.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <strong>Praesent commodo Nibh Etiam Sem Nullam</strong><br>
        <strong style=" color:#029f5b;"> <?php  echo $row->BookID; ;?></strong><br>
        Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem no inquiry so cordial   
        <a class="" href="#">» Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $r++; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: nice but carousel  run not correct i change one condition in your code if($r == 0 or $r%6==0) { ?>  and run correct but that time have not strat the beginning one time record complete run second time carousel not run repeatedly

Comment: first time run complete record in carousel second time time not start again slider from first row

Comment: Checked my answer now because i had modified after adding.

Comment: now better but first time when page load then slider not load page is blank  after page load  mean some time wait  then show book slider and  second i have 18 record  3 time slider move and then not slide again  but i want repeats again again.  18 record run continuously

Comment: Look at this example and i hope this will work for you.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: This answer really helpful.